# Resource collision after "Foursquare" dependency injection for Android native application development

Tags: android, code-injection, foursquare

Hello guys: I’m using the next scenario for Android native applications development:

Android Studio 3.6.2

Graddle plugin 3.6.2

Graddle version 5.6.4

Kotlin version 1.3.61

I write the next dependency injection in my build.graddle.

implementation 'com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.1.0'

When I build the project, and only after this injection (in packaging stage), I get this error:

Entry name 'res/drawable/notification_bg_low.xml' collided

As I have found in my personal search, in the project "build.properties" file, I add the next entry to fix the error:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'res/drawable/notification_bg_low.xml'
    }
}
```

The collision is solved, but another collissions appear. The collision (which are found one in each build process) are the next ones:

Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided

Entry name 'res/drawable/notification_bg.xml' collided

Entry name 'res/drawable/notification_bg_low.xml' collided

Entry name 'res/layout/notification_template_part_time.xml' collided

Entry name 'res/layout/notification_template_part_chronometer.xml' collided

Entry name 'resources.arsc' collided

The only way I have found so far to fix this is to add all this files in my Project build.graddle file:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'res/drawable/notification_bg.xml'
        exclude 'res/drawable/notification_bg_low.xml'
        exclude 'res/layout/notification_template_part_time.xml'
        exclude 'res/layout/notification_template_part_chronometer.xml'
        exclude 'resources.arsc'
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct solution.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it correct to exclude files in packaging?

Answer (score 0):

A few months late here but if you upgrade to version 1.1.1 that should fix the issue. There was a bad dependency included in the POM for the library.

On 1.1.0 you could get rid of it without messing with the packaging options by doing something like

```groovy
    implementation("com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.1.0") {
        exclude("com.google.android", "android")
    }
```